# Is there a way to disable automatic insertion of * characters in VIM multiline comments?

Tags: vim

I come from Emacs and I am not used to (and don't like) seeing tons of `*` characters in my multiline comments, so how do I tell VIM to disable auto-insertion of them?

I want comments to be from *this*

```
/*
 *
 *
 */
```

to *this*

```
/*


*/
```

Thanks in advance =D

Comment: If anyone feels like this question belongs somewhere else please tell me where to go to so I know better next time.

Comment: `set fo-=cro` Also read `:h 'formatoptions'` and `:h fo-table` You're free to ask vi-related questions here or at vi.stackexchange.net

Comment: As @Matt said, next time, feel free to visit [vi.se]! (Matt, I get the magic link with `[vi.se]` in comments. Works for other things too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described under [`:help format-comments`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#format-comments). The `*` is a *comment leader* (as defined by the [`'comments'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27comments%27) option) and may be inserted based on the [`'formatoptions'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27) option, whose values are documented under [`:help fo-table`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table). The following letters control comment leader insertion:

> `c`   Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment leader automatically. 
>   `r`   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting  in Insert mode.
>   `o`   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or 'O' in Normal mode.

So, to turn this off, use

```
:set fo-=c fo-=r fo-=o
```

(or short `:set fo-=cro` if they appear in that order).

As this option often is set by a *filetype plugin* (check via `:verbose set fo?`), you may need to override this (using `:setlocal`) in a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` to get rid of permanently.

Comment: Is it easier to use the method you said to make it permanent or use Vundle to do it? I think I read somewhere you can also use it for this purpose, I'd like to integrate this well with my dotfiles.

Comment: `~/.vim/after` is part of your dotfiles. Vundle is a _plugin manager_; it may add additional locations where you could potentially put this config, but it doesn't fundamentally change the approach.